# Get posts that matches specific terms of multiple custom taxonomies

Tags: loop, taxonomy, terms, get-posts

I'm working on a page that show a lot of products. My structure is

- Product (custom post type)
- -->Brand (custom taxonomy)
- ------>Brand A (custom term)
- ------>Brand B (custom term)
- -->Department (custom taxonomy).
- ------>Department A (custom term)
- ------>Department B (custom term)

Each product always has to have one brand AND one department. However, there may be a few products in each brand.

So, I need to do a list that shows me the all the products that matches both a specific brand AND a specific department, and also that let me print the name of the brand. i.e: In department A we have 3 products that matches Brand A.

Is there any way to do it? I'm able to filter either one a brand or a department, but not both at the same time.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is my code to get all the products of a specific department, and it's working great.

```
$args = array(
 'tax_query' => array(
     array(
         'taxonomy' => 'department',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => array( 'department-a' )
     ),
 ),
 'orderby' => 'title',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'post_type' => 'prod'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

 $term = $query->queried_object;

 while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>         

     <a  rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="producto btn btn-raised cardio-dark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
} ?>
```

But what I need is to **get the product's brand instead of product's name**, and that if 2 or more products have the same brand, the brand appear only one time. So I can produce a list as the described above. i.e: Department A has 2 "Brand A" products and one "Brand B" product.

Comment: Would be easier to give a helpful answer - to what otherwise appears to be as simple logic/syntax question - if you showed the specific code you're using or have tried.

Comment: Hi CK MacLeod, I've just updated my post to explain a little more what my problem is. Thanks.

Comment: So, what I understand from your question is that you have some number of "products" (custom post type "prod") with custom terms under "Department" and "Brand." 

The main ask is to produce a list broken down so that the brands that exist in each Department are enumerated. So something like this, prior to formatting adjustments:

"Department A"
- "Brand 1" (1)
- "Brand 2" (3)
- "Brand 4" (1); 
"Department B"
- "Brand 3" (2)
- "Brand 4" (4)

Etc. With the actual names within the quotes, and the numbers in parentheses tallying the quantities. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi CK; I have solved how to show which brands are in each department, but I have a problem of how to group the products that matches the same brand. I've posted and explained it better [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228271/group-posts-that-matches-a-term-in-a-loop)

Comment: Please do **NOT** post duplicates - you only hurt your chances of a helpful answer. Since your other dupe [has an answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/228271/1685), I am flagging this to be closed.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic It's not a duplicate, even if it looks that way. The OP was just lazy and copy/pasted the intro that matched both questions equally, so it _looked_ like a dupe. In fact it's two different questions and I reopened the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this problem. I'm copying the code because it may help someone :) I've found the solution by populating an arrray and checking if a brand is or is not there, so I only get each brand one time.

```
   <?php

    //Query to match department
    $args = array(
     'tax_query' => array(
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'department',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => array( 'department_name' )
         ),
     ),
     'orderby' => 'title',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'post_type' => 'prod', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

      // Array of brands
      $brands= array();

      $term = $query->queried_object;

     while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
         <!-- Loop to show the brand -->
         <?php
          $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'brabds' );
 // Loop por el array de marcas
          if ( $terms != null ){
            foreach( $terms as $term ) {

              // I want to check if my brand has only one product or more
              // Only one product
              if ($term ->count == 1){
                // I create a variable so I can check if it's in my brands array
                   $marca = $term->name;
                // If is not in array, push it there
                    if ( ! in_array($marca, $marcas)){
                        array_push($marcas, $marca);
                // This query is to link to a product and get some info
                        $tax_query = '';
                                    $tax_query[] = array('taxonomy' => 'brands','field' => 'term_id','terms' => $term->term_id);
                                    $term_post = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'prod','tax_query' => $tax_query));
                                    if (!empty($term_post)) {
                                        $term_post_link = get_permalink($term_post[0]->ID);
                                        $id_prod = url_to_postid($term_post_link);
                                        $nombre_prod = get_the_title($term_post[0]->ID);
                                        echo '<a title="'.$term->name.'" rel="'.$id_prod.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
                                    }
                    }
              }
              // Marcas MULTI
              else{
                // If there are more than a product, do the same thing but query as my needs
                    $marca = $term->name;                    
                    if ( ! in_array($marca, $marcas)){
                        array_push($marcas, $marca);
                        echo '<a rel="'.$term->term_id.'" title="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
                    }
              }
            }
          }
          // End loop
?>

    <?php
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
    } ?>
```